# Как на C++ подключиться к MySQL по SLL вручную (без MySQL Connector)?

Tags: c++, mysql, ssl

Предлагаемая разработчиками MySQL библиотека "Connector" слишком много весит - больше всего файла установщика моего приложения, и даже больше распакованного клиента. Неохота раздувать размер установщика в два раза и более. Плюс, насколько мне известно, SSL там не поддерживается. Поэтому хотел поинтересоваться по поводу того, как выполнить защищённое соединение с удалённым MySQL-сервером из приложения на C++ - чисто на сокетах?

Есть все файлы ключей и сертификатов, libssl... нет только понимания как в MySQL реализованы защищённые подключения и как мне из моего клиента подключиться к базе.

Подскажите пожалуйста порядок действий.

Comment: libmysqlclient?

Comment: @arrowd, а это не одно и то же, что и Connertor? Мне под Windows надо, желательно lib*.a для MinGW. И всё таки это лишние 6 мб к клиенту, в котором и так уже реализован сетевой функционал - осталось только к базе подключиться, чтобы просто передавать запросы по сокетам... Как-то не рационально ради одной небольшой задачи раздувать размер клиента на несколько мб.

Comment: Ну это самый родной и низкоуровневый клиент к MySQL, поэтому я сомневаюсь, что вы найдете что-то тоньше. Вы же не думаете, что SQL запросы прямо текстом шлются на сервер? Тогда не было бы нужды в такой штуке как libmysqlclient.

Comment: @arrowd, не знаете случайно, можно ли его установить через msys2 - pacman?

Comment: Возможно, сможет помочь коннектор от MariaDB: они были совместимы с MySQL и у них на сайте раздают не только исходники, но и собранные библиотеки. И да, с MinGW виндовые *.lib вполне нормально линковались (я пробовал их коннектор пару лет назад. Кажется, тогда использовал MinGW gcc 4.9).